# Handling long Pod response times in a Service

Tags: service, deployment, kubernetes, httprequest, kubernetes-ingress

Given the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30001
      name: server
selector:
  app: nginx
```

How would one configure the Service and Deployment here (or if needed, an Ingress object) so that when a Pod takes more than *n* seconds to return a HTTP response, the Service will try the request on another `nginx-deployment` Pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) Services are based on simple iptables rules.
Traffic is NAT'ed only to destination pod. There are no layers you can adjust, for example, timeouts and set quality of services based on it.